# What signal (VCC or ground) is connected to the top layer in a four layer PCB with a separate ground plane?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers

I am designing four layer PCB for the first time. I have designed two layer PCBs before. If we dedicate the inner plane for the ground, then which signal should be on the top layer copper pour region? Is it VCC, GND, or signal?

Comment: Why have a top layer pour? The answer to that will answer what to connect it to. If there's no answer, you have no reason for a top layer pour. Engineering, not magic, guides our actions!

Comment: Use it for whatever you want. Just don't leave it floating.

Comment: Before contemplating Marcus' important comment, also first answer for yourself: A) Why do I need 4 layers? B) which layers are tightly coupled? c) where are all the current loopa?